# How to prevent page refreshes on tab switching in IE7?

Tags: xhtml, internet-explorer-7, tabs, refresh

For a specific website (internal to network, coded in XHTML) the behavior in IE6 was that when ever the window is re-sized or restored the page refreshes.

Since IE6 doesn't have tabs I upgraded to IE7 - but the problem with IE7 is whenever we switch from one tab to another, its makes the active tab's page to refresh, and this happens all the time.

After googling a bit, I found a temporary solution, (to disable the Meta-Refresh property in IE settings). This has resolved the problem to some extent but still refreshes happens.

**Is there a way to permanently disable the refreshing of page when tabs are switched ?**

Comment: The specific website, I am talking about is an application and I do not have privileges to edit its code(pages).
Also, the reason I am not switching to IE8 is I am unsure if the application's webpages are compatible with IE8.

Comment: I think this would belong on superuser

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your solution is to use something along the lines of:

```
<!--[if IE #]>
Special instructions for IE # here
Rather than on restored just leave your code to refresh in resize. 
Depending on what your page is doing you most likely may not need it to 
refresh on resize using IE8+.
<![endif]-->
```

Otherwise I would just plan on the IE8+ being the used browser and not worry about what it does in IE6 anymore.

Comment: With Google Chrome, Firefox and IE8 out and about I don't know why you would want to be using IE7. But it depends on circumstances I guess.

Comment: Refer the comment I added above.

Comment: .. even now there are many companies which use IE6 for intranets. Chrome/FF is not even considered for intranet :)

Comment: it may be because of the control it gives to the administrators. you can control each and every option.

Comment: @Shoban Where I am currently working we are using chrome or FF and we push it to clients with our software pretty hard. IE doesn't comply with standards and until they do it is the worse piece of software. As for that I understand that most people do use it but there is nothing wrong with changing for the better if you are going from 6-7 anyways? Also I did say "It depends on circumstances".